# RabbitMQ Alternate Exchange and exchange to exchange binding

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

RabbitMQ v3.7.8

*(AE = alternate exchange)*

---

The documentation states:

> Whenever an exchange with a configured AE cannot route a message to
>   any queue, it publishes the message to the specified AE instead.

It also explains:

> If an AE cannot
>   route a message, it in turn publishes the message to its AE, if it has
>   one configured. This process continues until either the message is
>   successfully routed, the end of the chain of AEs is reached, or an AE
>   is encountered which has already attempted to route the message.

I assume `any queue` means `any queue in the chain` much in the same way the AE is resolved.

---

### Expect `FOO_Alt` to be triggered.

[image]

---

### Expect `FOO_Alt` ***not*** to be triggered.

[image]

---

Are my expectations correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should be correct. Of course, the best way to know is to try it out.